# Predicate Logic using Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

$$\lnot \forall y: Y.A\vdash \exists y: Y.(A\rightarrow B)$$

Need to prove that LHS entails RHS, however I'm confused as to how to do it. Never used a negation on a universal quantifier before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HINT $$\lnot \forall y: Y.A \equiv \exists y: \lnot Y.A$$

Comment: Thanks, I researched on De Morgan's for Quantifiers and figured it out!